# TODO task netbeans php

Tags: netbeans, todo

I'm using netbeans to develop web applications using php and javascript.

I was using eclipse and I could list all my tasks using the `//TODO` comment.

I don't understand how does it works on netbeans.

So is there a solution to create tasks using comment and how can I access to my task list ?

I have netbeans 7.4 on OSX

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check Tools|Options|Misc.|Action Items, there is a list of comments to IDE should look for in your code. Now open Window|Action Items and it will show all found tasks

Comment: I trying this also but can find action items you spoke about see my screen shot at http://imgur.com/0bz3WGw

Comment: Seems like it has moved to the Team category

Comment: It depends on when skin you're using.

Answer (score 5):

In Netbeans 8.0.2 (my current) Action Items list is present in Tools|Options|Team|Action Items. And then, like @ladar said: Window|Action Items.

Answer (score 3):

In NetBeans IDE 8.1 this is still in:

- Window | Action Items

or there is the shortcut:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

In project you can use not only `// TODO` comment, but also `// FIXME` and other.

Full list of the special comments you can find and edit in:

- Tools | Options | Team | Action Items

https://netbeans.org/features/ide/

> The Action Items window automatically scans your code and lists commented lines containing words such as "TODO" or "FIXME", as well as lines with compilation errors, quick fixes, and style warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have Netbeans 8.0.2, the shortcut "Ctrl+6" may work for you, too.